# Why does repeatedly calling "iter(a).next()" on a list "a" never return more than the first list item?

Tags: python, iterator

The following code confuses me:

```
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> iter(a)
<listiterator object at 0x7f3e9920cf50>
>>> iter(a).next()
0
>>> iter(a).next()
0
>>> iter(a).next()
0
```

`next()` is always returning 0. So, how does the `iter` function work?

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29570348/2301450

Comment: @vaultah, I think it is almost an exact duplicate

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, Sorry, I want to know how `*([iter(a)]*2)` works, especially `*` in python.

Comment: Please don't add new questions to your question post. Stick to one problem per post please.

Comment: @AlexanderYau: sorry, no, I won't do that. I put in work to answer your question, people have found my answer helpful. You can't ask others to destroy their contributions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating a *new* iterator each time. Each new iterator starts at the beginning, they are all independent.

Create the iterator once, then iterate over that one instance:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a_iter = iter(a)
>>> next(a_iter)
0
>>> next(a_iter)
1
>>> next(a_iter)
2
```

I used the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) rather than calling the `iterator.next()` method; Python 3 renames the latter to `iterator.__next__()` but the `next()` function will call the right 'spelling', just like `len()` is used to call `object.__len__`.

Comment: how `zip(*([iter(a)]*2))` works, and what is `*` mean in python, `*` in `C` is get the value of a pointer.

Comment: See [What does \*\* (double star) and \* (star) do for Python parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901) for what the `*` does.

Comment: `[iter(a)] * 2` produces a list with two references to one iterator. `zip(*(...))` applies those two references as arguments to the `zip()` function.

Comment: See [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/434287) for what it is used for.