# When to use __iter__() vs iter()?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a class which implements an `__iter__()` function, is it preferred to use `iter(obj)` or calling `obj.__iter__()` directly? Are there any real differences besides having to type 5 characters less with the magic function?

In contrast: For `next()` and `__next__()` I can see an advantage for having a default value with the magic function.

Comment: `iter()` is not magic - it is, what you are supposed to be using ...

Comment: [reading this and the linked maybe-dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709805/how-does-the-python-iter-function-work) might help

Comment: Why am I supposed to use iter() over __iter__()? Is there any real advantage except I have to type less?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I am not trying to understand what iter() does. I am trying to understand its advantage over __iter__()

Comment: In general, `__dunder__` methods implement the behaviour, but you trigger it with functions like `iter()` or `next()` or `len()`. Those functions often add a little extra behaviour.

Comment: @deceze OK, I understand that from a best-practice view. But in this case, there is no extra behaviour and thus no real advantage, right?

Comment: you want to use `iter()`. the advantage is one of cleaner code/convention.

Comment: It's largely about duck typing too. You implement `__iter__` on a custom object to make it iterable. But code that wants to iterate something should not necessarily know or care *how* that object is iterable, it should use `iter()` to leave the details to it.

Comment: Never use an __ leading variable. The whole idea is a conventional difference and thus while it usually does the same things, the idea is you treat __ as "private" functionality, so to speak, though python does not force private functions.

Comment: @Ruehri You are free to use `__iter__()` until it is removed in some future release and your code bricks. Listen to @PatrickArtner :-).

Comment: If I read up on [iter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) it also says it will work with either `__iter__()` or `__getitem()__` implementing classes - from a consumer perspective it abstracts of either one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference is mostly just convenience. It's less typing and less symbols to read, and so faster to read. However, the various builtin functions (eg. `iter`, `len` et al.) usually do a little type checking to catch errors early. If you wrote a customer `__iter__` method and it *returned* `2`, then invoking `obj.__iter__()` wouldn't catch that, but `iter(obj)` throws a type error. eg.

```
>>> class X:
    def __iter__(self):
        return 2

>>> x = X()
>>> x.__iter__()
2
>>> iter(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 1, in <module>
    iter(x)
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'int'
```

`iter` also implements the iterator protocol for objects that have no `__iter__`, but do implement the sequence protocol. That is, they have a `__getitem__` method which implements a sequence starting at index 0 and raises an IndexError for indexes not in bounds. This is an older feature of python and not really something new code should be using. eg.

```
>>> class Y:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if 0 <= index < 5:
            return index ** 2
        else:
            raise IndexError(index)

>>> list(iter(Y()))  # iter not strictly needed here
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

When should you use `__iter__`? This might not be so relevant to `__iter__`, but if you need access to the implementation of method that the parent class uses then it is best to invoke such methods in the style `super().__<dunder_method>__()` (using Python 3 style super usage). eg.

```
>>> class BizzareList(list):
    def __iter__(self):
        for item in super().__iter__():
            yield item * 10

>>> l = BizzareList(range(5))
>>> l  # normal access
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l[0]  # also normal access
0
>>> tuple(iter(l))  # iter not strictly needed here
(0, 10, 20, 30, 40)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `iter()` function (which in turn calls the **iter**() method) is a python built-in function that returns an
iterator from them. You can opt to use `iter(obj)` or `obj.__iter__()`, they are simply the same thing. Its just
that `__iter__()` is a user-defined function and calling it will just do what the written code asks it to do.
On the other hand, calling the `iter()` function will in turn call the user-defined `__iter__()` function and run
the same code. However, `iter()` will also run a built-in 'type' checking, in which if the customized `__iter__()`
doesn't return an iterator object, it would throw an error.
*The same thing applies to `next()` & `__next__()`.

Thus, `iter(obj) ~= obj.__iter__()`,
`next(obj) ~= obj.__next__()`

Note that `__iter__()` and `__next__()` must be defined by the user when creating a class if the object os intended
to be an iterator.

Source: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/iterator

Comment: Technically, this is not true. In order to be iterable, `__iter__` needs to be defined, which should return an iterator, ie., something that implements `__next__`.

Comment: Can't you iterate over a class with just `__len__` and `__getitem__`?